# Javascript variable is not reading in this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, atom-editor, nodemon

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello from the server');
});
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('App running on port ${ port }...');
});
```

When I run this code in my terminal this is showing as

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
App running on port ${port}...
```

Comment: You need [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of a single quote

Answer (score 1):

You can only use string interpolation with [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
console.log(`App running on port ${ port }...`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `back tics` instead of `single quotes`. Your code

```
  console.log('App running on port ${ port }...');
```

should change to:

```
  console.log(`App running on port ${ port }...`);
```

Refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use this code:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello from the server");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Or you can change the code

```
'App running on port ${port}...'
```

to

```
`App running on port ${port}...`
```

Answer (score 0):

use string template literals

```js
console.log(`App running on port ${port}... `)
```

> Instead of

```js
console.log('App running on port ${port}...')
```